# How to output string on command line or in a file, depending on a parameter, in C#?

Tags: c#

How to output string on command line or in a file, depending on a parameter, in C#?

I have parameter:

```
bool console = true; // or false
```

then I have some code that creates a StringBuilder.
I want to output to either Console or to a StreamWriter,
based on the console variable.

The tricky part is:

1. I need to write in small pieces, not a whole string at a time
2. Given 1) I will end up with code like:

   ```
   if (console ) {
       Console.WriteLine(someString);
   } else {
       using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file)) {
           writer.WriteLine(someString);
       }
   }
   ```

every single time I need to add to the string!

So how do I escape this code bloat?

Answer (score 3):

You do not need to create an interface yourself; you can simply change your code to take a TextWriter as an input:

```
private void DoSomethingAndWriteLog(TextWriter writer)
{
    // Do something
    var someString = "Test";
    writer.WriteLine(someString);
}
```

Then you can call this method both using Console.[Out](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.out%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and a custom TextWriter:

```
if (console)
{
    DoSomethingAndWriteLog(Console.Out);
} 
else 
{
    using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(file)) 
    {
        DoSomethingAndWriteToLog(writer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As a generalized case, you define an output writer interface,

```
interface IOutputWriter
{
    void WriteLine(string s);
}
```

then write 2 classes that conform to that interface, and inject the appropriate one into your code.

```
void YourCode (IOutputWriter writer)
{ 
     // ...
     writer.WriteLine(output);
}

void Main()
{
    IOutputWriter writer;
    if (console)
    { 
        writer = new ConsoleWriter();
    }
    else
    { 
        writer = new StreamWriter();
    }
    YourCode (writer);

}
```

You can then later define new implementations of `IOutputWriter` to cope with new requirements (eg: PrinterWriter, DatabaseWriter, etc).

Answer (score 2):

You can make Console.WriteLine output to file, by invoking Console.SetOut and passing a StreamWriter as a parameter:

```
if (needToOutputToFile)
{
    Console.SetOut (streamWriter);
}
Console.WriteLine ("This is written in a file, if needToOutputToFile is true");
```

Comment: +1 This is the answer. However, I reckon the OP should be using `Write` rather than `WriteLine` given *"I need to write in small pieces, not a whole string at a time"*.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `Console.Out` standard writer and *trenary operator*:

```
  using (TextWriter writer = console ? Console.Out : new StreamWriter(file)) {
    ...
    writer.WriteLine(someString);
    ...
  }
```